# How do I forward multicast traffic between 2 different LANs using iptables?

Tags: iptables, multicast

**Goal:**

Need lmc or ["LAN Messenger"](http://lanmsngr.sourceforge.net/) to work on 2 lans separated by a Linux gateway using iptables.

**Information:**

- Must be this program "LAN Messenger".
- Lmc uses multicast address 239.255.100.100:50000 to see users, then creates a tcp connection for chat.
- lan1 = olan1 = 192.168.2.0/24: gateway is a smart switch "Linksys Etherfast router" with filter multicast disabled.
- lan2 = slan1 = 10.10.10.0/24: gateway is the linux box
- gateway pc = Ubuntu 14 server. iptables to forward some traffic between lans.

**iptable rules:**

*filter table:*

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i slan1 -o olan1 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m iprange --src-range 192.168.2.100-192.168.2.254 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i olan1 -o slan1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i olan1 -o slan1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9696 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i olan1 -o slan1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 50000 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i olan1 -o slan1 -p udp -m udp --dport 50000 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 224.0.0.0/4 -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p igmp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i olan1 -o slan1 -j DROP
```

*nat table:*

```
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERAD
```

*Rules that I thought should forward multicast traffic:*

```
-A FORWARD -i olan1 -o slan1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 50000 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i olan1 -o slan1 -p udp -m udp --dport 50000 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 224.0.0.0/4 -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p igmp -j ACCEPT
```

Monitored the traffic of the gateway using tcpdump, I never saw multicast traffic go through as I changed iptable rules.

**Will iptables forward multicast traff**ic?

**Do I need to use a multicast routing daemon or proxy like `pimd` or `smcroute`?**

Comment: Doesn't multicast use some broadcasting as well? Don't think a gateway will forward broadcast traffic.

Comment: I am starting to that that is so. Is that what the programs `pimd` and `smcroute` do?

Comment: Why does it have to be `iptables`, and not a multicast routing demon like [mrouted](http://troglobit.github.io/mrouted.html) or similar (which is the *intended* way to handle this situation)? I am not even sure you actually *can* do this with `iptables`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tested `smcroute` with two network namespaces and two `veth` pairs. Setup:

```
ns1         <-- main namespace -->    ns2
10.0.0.1 -- 10.0.0.254  10.0.1.254 -- 10.0.1.1
veth0b      veth0a          veth1a    veth1b
```

The Debian `smcroute` package is version 2.0.0, and doesn't seem to support virtual eth, so I installed version 2.3.1 from the [smcroute homepage](http://troglobit.github.io/smcroute.html). The [multicast route howto](http://troglobit.github.io/multicast-howto.html) of `smcroute` is also very helpful.

I used the `ssmping` package to test multicasts. I ran `ssmpingd` in ns2, while pinging with `ssmping -4 -I veth0b 10.0.1.1` from ns1. These are source-specific multicasts (SSM) using group `232.43.211.234`, you can also test any-source multicasts (ASM) with `asmping`. I don't know what LAN messenger uses.

I enabled forwarding in the main namespace to allow the unicast ping requests to get through, then did

```
smcroutectl add veth1a 10.0.1.1 232.43.211.234 veth0a
```

and everything worked fine. I would expect it also to work, adjusted to your setup, though you also may have to `smcroutectl join` to tell your switches they should forward multicasts properly. Multiple `tcpdump` terminal windows on all relevant interfaces greatly help with debugging.

I found the following pieces of information interesting:

> To be able to setup multicast routes a program must connect to the
>    multicast routing socket in the kernel, when that socket is closed, which
>    is done automatically when a UNIX program ends, the kernel cleans up all
>    routes.

This means if you intend to use the multicast routing feature of the kernel, you *must* use a demon, not a commandline tool.

For static vs. dynamic routing, it says:

> The intended purpose of smcroute is to aid in situations where dynamic
>   multicast routing does not work properly.  However, a dynamic multicast
>   routing protocol is in nearly all cases the preferred solution.  The reason
>   for this is their ability to translate Layer-3 signalling to Layer-2 and
>   vice versa (IGMP or MLD).

Finally, pay close attention to the TTL that is produced by your LAN messenger, see [multicast FAQ](http://troglobit.github.io/multicast-howto.html) at the end.

Comment: Thank you for you detailed answer. I am a little fuzzy about vethX. Are these virtual adapters? Where did you create them? Are the virtual adapters a "pipe" between the 2 physical adapters?

Comment: If I created a virtual "pipe" will that help the routing table adjustment I made? See my answer:

Comment: Thank you again. I will accept you answer because I followed your advice on what program to use, the TTL info, and all the extra info you included.

Comment: Great to see my work on SMCRoute and the HowTo has helped people :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay it looks like `iptables` *alone* is NOT the way to go.

<strike>I will try `smcroute` and/or `pimd` from the ubuntu repositories. So far I have not been able to make either one work.</strike>

Using smcroute:

---

`iptables`

```
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i slan1 -o olan1 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p igmp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i olan1 -o slan1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 50000 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i olan1 -o slan1 -p udp -m udp --dport 50000 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A PREROUTING -d 239.255.100.100/32 -j TTL --ttl-set 64
```

[smcroute 2.3.1](ftp://ftp.troglobit.com/smcroute/smcroute-2.3.1.tar.xz) from troglobit.

Extracted to `/opt`

`./configure` used default options.

configuration file at:

`/usr/local/etc/smcroute.conf`

```
#phyint olan1 enable ttl-threshold 1
phyint olan1 enable ttl-threshold 5
phyint slan1 enable ttl-threshold 5
mgroup from olan1 group 239.255.100.100
mgroup from slan1 group 239.255.100.100
mroute from olan1 group 239.255.100.100 to slan1
mroute from slan1 group 239.255.100.100 to olan
```

- ttl-threshold -- is that minimum threshold?
- if the TTL on my packet is 1 does that mean the phyint will... ignore it. Changed to 5 just in case.

`sudo smcrouted`

`sudo smcroutectl show groups`

```
GROUP (S,G)                        INBOUND                                                                                                    
(*, 239.255.100.100)               slan1
(*, 239.255.100.100)               olan1
```

`sudo smcroutectl show routs`

```
ROUTE (S,G)                        INBOUND          PACKETS    BYTES  OUTBOUND                                                                
(*, 239.255.100.100)               slan1                  0        0  olan1
(*, 239.255.100.100)               olan1                  0        0  slan1
(10.10.10.154, 239.255.100.100)    slan1                  2      344  olan1
(192.168.2.53, 239.255.255.250)    olan1                  4      776 
(10.10.10.101, 239.255.100.100)    slan1                  1       32  olan1
(192.168.2.101, 239.255.100.100)   olan1                  1       32  slan1
(10.10.10.1, 239.255.100.100)      slan1                  2       64  olan1
```

Not quite everybody...

On a WinXP multi-homed pc had to change a route:

`route add 224.0.0.0 mask 240.0.0.0 10.10.10.153`

*need to use the interface number in place of the nic ip address...*

- The metric goes to 1. Is this a TTL issue...

`sudo smcroutectl show routs`

```
ROUTE (S,G)                        INBOUND          PACKETS    BYTES  OUTBOUND
(*, 239.255.100.100)               slan1                  0        0  olan1
(*, 239.255.100.100)               olan1                  0        0  slan1
(192.168.2.53, 239.255.255.250)    olan1                  4      776 
(10.10.10.153, 239.255.100.100)    slan1                  1       32  olan1
```

---

`LAN Messenger 1.2.32 network preferences`

- Connection Timeout (seconds) -- max out value
- Maximum number of retries -- max out value

---

Make smcroute a daemon with Upstart on Ubuntu 14

`/etc/init/smcroute.conf`

```
# Upstart for custom compiled smcroute
## jc 2017 08 24
description "SMCRoute, a static multicast router"
author      "jc"
# Stanzas
# Stanzas control when and how a process is started and stopped
# See a list of stanzas here: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Stanzas#respawn
# When to start the service
# start on runlevel [2345]
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE!=lo) or runlevel [2345]
# When to stop the service
#stop on runlevel [016]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
# Automatically restart process if crashed
expect fork
respawn
exec /usr/local/sbin/smcrouted -N -f /usr/local/etc/smcroute.conf -d 10 -l notice
```

Everything seems to work. Will let things run for a while with random reboots and occasional network outages, normal stuff.

**TODO**

- <strike>Make smcroute a daemon</strike>
- <strike>Make route additions persistent</strike>
- Verify iptables rule... is required
- <strike>Make Win7 pc see subnet</strike>