# Filter IPTV content

Tags: iptables, raspberry-pi

my internet provider has tv service (IPTV). The infrastructure is

```
ONT-> Router (LAN- wifi) -> TV deco
```

I want to filter content from TV (youtube app). Then i add raspberry with 2 interfaces

```
ONT-> Router -> Raspberry -> TV Deco
```

if i route traffic in Raspberry with iptables

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo /sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
sudo /sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

TV deco has internet, but can not view tv content

if i create a bridge

```
sudo ip link set dev br0 up
sudo ip link set dev eth0 master br0
sudo ip link set dev eth1 master br0
```

I have TV content, but not internet

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, I have very little network background, but I'm sure you need to accept/NAT IGMP traffic, this stackoverflow post looks that might be helpful for you:
[How do I forward multicast traffic between 2 differant lans using iptables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386490/how-do-i-forward-multicast-traffic-between-2-differant-lans-using-iptables)

Comment: finally fix the problem by installing in my raspberry igmpproxy [link](https://github.com/pali/igmpproxy)